# What is the derivative of (Ax)'

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f(x)=(Ax)^T$ where A is a matrix and x is a vector. How do you explain that $f'(x)=(Ax)^T$? Specifically, that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x) (y) = (Ay)^T$.

I can't seem to do it rigorously. And I can't find any references on this.

Comment: First you need the definition for "derivative" of a function of many variables (or a function of a vector).  What is the one you are using?  (Without a definition, there is no hope of proving anything about it.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to GEdgar for the hint to go back to first principles.

Here's my take, updated. I use the directional derivative in the direction of $u$ as the definition of the derivative... I'm possibly mangling my notation...

\[ \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}(u) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x + h u) - f(x)}{h}\]

So, when $f(x) = (Ax)^T$,

\[ \begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}(u) &=& \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{(A(x + h u))^T - (Ax)^T}{h}\\
&=& \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{(A(hu))^T}{h}\\
&=& (Au)^T
\end{eqnarray}
\]

In fact this works for any linear function $g$, i..e, for $g$ linear and $f(x)=(g(x))^T$, then $f'(x)(u)=(g'(x)(u))^T$.

Comment: +1.You can also use the linear transformation definition of the total derivative,but that will give you the same answer. When you have no idea how to solve something, ALWAYS go back to the definition. It may not give you the answer,but more often then not it'll point you in the right direction.